# Client to server model authentication

Tags: java, authentication, client, server

I am creating a `client` `server` model. This all works but I need something like an `authenticator` so not everyone can just connect with the `server` and send random data. I was thinking of sending an `authentication` request to the `server` and only allow `clients` which are `authenticated` to send data to the `server`. With `authenticating` I do not mean having different accounts and such, there would only be one which each client would use to `authenticate`. Although I don't know if this is the best way to do it and if it's safe.

Is this a good way to do it or should I do it on another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ssl with client authentication.